# RStudio can't find installed packages

Tags: r

I recently updated to osx Sierra and now Rstudio can't find my packages. But it seems that it is looking in the right place (DESeq2 is nr. 30 on the list):

```
> library(DESeq2)
Error in library(DESeq2) : there is no package called ‘DESeq2’

> .libPaths()
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library"

> list.files("/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library")
  [1] "acepack"              "airway"               "annotate"             "AnnotationDbi"        "assertthat"           "base"                
  [7] "base64enc"            "BH"                   "Biobase"              "BiocGenerics"         "BiocInstaller"        "BiocParallel"        
 [13] "BiocStyle"            "biomaRt"              "Biostrings"           "bitops"               "boot"                 "caTools"             
 [19] "chron"                "class"                "cluster"              "codetools"            "colorspace"           "compiler"            
 [25] "corpcor"              "curl"                 "data.table"           "datasets"             "DBI"                  "DESeq2"              
 [31] "dichromat"            "digest"               "doParallel"           "dplyr"                "edgeR"                "ellipse"             
 [37] "evaluate"             "file86d32aa98203"     "foreach"              "foreign"              "formatR"              "Formula"             
 [43] "futile.logger"        "futile.options"       "gdata"                "genefilter"           "geneplotter"          "GenomeInfoDb"        
 [49] "GenomicAlignments"    "GenomicFeatures"      "GenomicRanges"        "ggplot2"              "gplots"               "graphics"            
 [55] "grDevices"            "grid"                 "gridBase"             "gridExtra"            "gtable"               "gtools"              
 [61] "highr"                "Hmisc"                "htmlTable"            "htmltools"            "htmlwidgets"          "httpuv"              
 [67] "httr"                 "igraph"               "IRanges"              "irlba"                "iterators"            "jsonlite"            
 [73] "KernSmooth"           "knitr"                "labeling"             "lambda.r"             "lattice"              "latticeExtra"        
 [79] "lazyeval"             "limma"                "locfit"               "magrittr"             "markdown"             "MASS"                
 [85] "Matrix"               "methods"              "mgcv"                 "mime"                 "mixOmics"             "munsell"             
 [91] "nlme"                 "NMF"                  "nnet"                 "openssl"              "parallel"             "pheatmap"            
 [97] "pkgmaker"             "plyr"                 "R.cache"              "R.methodsS3"          "R.oo"                 "R.utils"             
[103] "R6"                   "rafalib"              "RColorBrewer"         "Rcpp"                 "RcppArmadillo"        "RCurl"               
[109] "registry"             "repmis"               "reshape"              "reshape2"             "rgl"                  "rmarkdown"           
[115] "rngtools"             "rpart"                "Rsamtools"            "RSQLite"              "rtracklayer"          "S4Vectors"           
[121] "scales"               "shiny"                "snow"                 "sourcetools"          "spatial"              "splines"             
[127] "stats"                "stats4"               "stringi"              "stringr"              "SummarizedExperiment" "survival"            
[133] "tcltk"                "tibble"               "tidyr"                "tools"                "translations"         "utils"               
[139] "viridis"              "XML"                  "xtable"               "XVector"              "yaml"                 "zlibbioc"
```

Comment: Have you checked `/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library`? Is there a folder called DESeq2?

Comment: Yes, but permission denied. I guess that's the problem...

Comment: Can you use chmod or something like this with mac to give permission to the folder (I use Ubuntu not Mac...)?

Comment: Can I copy the entire directory to another location and change where R/RStudio looks for and installs packages?

Comment: No, work computer so I can't change permissions

Comment: That should work (copy and change lib path)!